# Two ajax requests on same event at same time . what should be the typical behaviour? how it is different if request is synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

In the following javascript code, I am sending two Ajax request at the same time.
After analysis using Firebug, I came to unusual conclusion that :
*"which ever (Ajax) response is coming first is printing last"*.

**Problem 2:** if I assign the Ajax url destination to a random string (say "abcd") [which don't exist] then total number of ajax call will be increased to 3?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $("#loadingimg").show();

    $.ajax({
      url: form_url, 
      type: form_method,      
      data: form_data,     
      cache: false,
      success: function(returnhtml){                          
        alert ("a");
        // $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
        // $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
      }           
    });   

    $.ajax({
      url: form_url, 
      type: form_method,      
      data: form_data,     
      cache: false,
      success: function(returnhtml){                          
        // $("#duplicate").html(returnhtml); 
        // $("#loadingimg").hide();
        alert("b");
      }           
    }); 
  });
});
```

Please refer the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atom217/Uwcuz/732/).

Comment: `"which ever (ajax)response is coming first is printing last"` - Maybe, maybe not.  It might indeed be the case in your particular scenario that this is the result most of the time.  AJAX is, by definition, asynchronous.  There's no guarantee which one will "finish" first (or at all).  "Problem 2" doesn't make a lot of sense, can you elaborate?  In fact, what is your question at all?

Comment: do you need them to happen in a particular order?

Comment: i can not confirm. using the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/d66DN/](http://jsfiddle.net/d66DN/) you can see the first return alert first. also if you do a request to a random url you get a 301:premanently removed. you get 3 if you change only one url, change both you get 4.

Comment: @David you can confirm same by running firebug tool.

Answer (score 18):

Gaurav, you have an error, at the end of the 1st $.ajax it must end as `),` and 2nd as `)`.

You can't end with `;`

```js
var result1;
var result2;
$.when(
    $.ajax({ // First Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){     
                result1 = returnhtml;                  
        }           
    }),

    $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
            result2 = returnhtml;     
        }           
    })

).then(function() {
    $('#result1').html(result1);
    $('#result2').html(result2);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but I will try to give you some information. Like David said It may seem that the first request is the last one responding, but that will vary under many circumstances. There are different ways you could do this to control the outcome or order of the requests.

1) Upon success of the first request you could initiate the second request. I don't recommend this for speed purposes as your requests aren't running in parallel.

```
$.ajax({ // First Request
    url: form_url, 
    type: form_method,      
    data: form_data,     
    cache: false,
    success: function(returnhtml){     
        $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
               // $("#duplicate").html(returnhtml); 
               // $("#loadingimg").hide();
                alert("b");
            }           
        }); 
       alert ("a");
       // $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
       // $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
       }           
    });
```

2) If you need to have both requests responses at the same time, the preferred method would likely be jQuery deferred. This will make both requests run in parallel, and once both responses are received you can proceed as you would have.

Something Like this:

```
var result1;
var result2;
$.when(
    $.ajax({ // First Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){     
                result1 = returnhtml;                  
        }           
    }); 

    $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
            result2 = returnhtml;     
        }           
    }); 

).then(function() {
    $('#result1').html(result1);
    $('#result2').html(result2);
});
```

Check out:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Does this help or answer any of your questions?

Answer (score 1):

Or use `server_response` in your code. The script begin with condition:

```
if (recherche1.length>1) {
    $.ajax({ // First Request
        type :"GET",
        url : "result.php",
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(server_response){     
            $('.price1').html(server_response).show();                  
        }           
    }),

    $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
        type :"GET",
        url : "result2.php",
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(server_response){                          
            $('.price2').html(server_response).show();      
        }           
    });
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
var result1;
var result2;
$.when(
    $.ajax({ // First Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){     
                result1 = returnhtml;                  
        }           
    }); 

    $.ajax({ //Seconds Request
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
            result2 = returnhtml;     
        }           
    }); 

).then(function() {
    $('#result1').html(result1);
    $('#result2').html(result2);
});
```

Comment: hello  Gaurav you given example already wrxsti answred same example