# pass both php variable and input form values for two other pages at a time using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

page1.php

```
<?php
   echo $first;
   echo $secound;
   echo $third;
   echo $four;
?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="five" value=""></input>
    <input type="text" name="six" value=""></input>
    <input type="text" name="seven" value=""></input>
</form>
<button class="button">Submit</button>
```

I want to pass all this 4 php variables and 3 inputs values in form using ajax to the pages called 'page2.php' 'page3.php' when the button is clicked.
And I should get back the results from page2 and page3 and display it on page1.php saying like successful.

Comment: sorry.. It is unclear for me... Show your efforts here for doing whatever you want..

Comment: Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988250/two-ajax-request-on-same-event-at-same-time-what-should-be-typical-behaviour

Comment: where is the ajax function???

Answer (score 0):

You just cant access a server side variable directly into a jquery or javascript. you need to echo the variables in some html elements before you can access it like hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but if you have more `php` variables, it would be better to use hidden input to submit all of them.

```
<?php
   echo $first;
   echo $secound;
   echo $third;
   echo $four;
?>
<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text" name="five" value=""></input>
  <input type="text" name="six" value=""></input>
  <input type="text" name="seven" value=""></input>
</form>
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="submitForm()" class="button" >Submit</a>
<br>
<div id="ajax_results"></div>

function submitForm(){
   var phpVars = "&first=<?php echo $first;?>&second=<?php echo $second;?>&third=<?php echo $third;?>&four=<?php echo $four;?>";

   //page2.php ajax
   $.ajax({

        url: "page2.php",
        data: $("#my_form").serialize()+phpVars,
        type: "post",
        success: function(response){
            $("#ajax_results").html(response);
        }

   });

   //page3.php ajax
   $.ajax({

        url: "page3.php",
        data: $("#my_form").serialize()+phpVars,
        type: "post",
        success: function(response){
            $("#ajax_results").append("<h2>Page3 Ajax Result</h2>"+response);
        }

   });
}
```

Comment: how to receive input value at page 2 and 3

Comment: i want to redirect my page if i get success response from ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
Give id same as name in your form
for the following lines
  <input type="text" id="five" name="five" value=""></input>
  <input type="text" id="six" name="six" value=""></input>
  <input type="text" id="seven" name="seven" value=""></input>

then do like this in jquery.

    <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".button").click(function(event){

            $.post("page1.php",
            {
              first: "<?php echo $first ?>",
              secound: "<?php echo $secound ?>",
              third: "<?php echo $third ?>",
              four: "<?php echo $four ?>",
              five: $('#five').val();
              six: $('#six').val();
              seven: $('#seven').val();

            },
            function(data,status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                //do something
            });

            $.post("page2.php",
            {
              first: "<?php echo $first ?>",
              secound: "<?php echo $secound ?>",
              third: "<?php echo $third ?>",
              four: "<?php echo $four ?>",
              five: $('#five').val();
              six: $('#six').val();
              seven: $('#seven').val();

            },
            function(data,status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                //do something
            }); 
        });

     });
    </script>
```

Comment: page1.php is the page where i place the above scrip. so, should i mention page1.php or do we have any other logic for it?

Comment: You can place the script in some other page, is the simple solution.Sorry for being late.