# Sending two AJAX requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am probably missing something very simple here, but what I am trying to do is update two `divs` on my page with AJAX requests that are called at the same time when an item is clicked.

I have looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988250/two-ajax-requests-on-same-event-at-same-time-what-should-be-the-typical-behavi)
but unfortunately I am still missing something in the code.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.details', function(event) {
    //  $(this) = your current element that clicked.
    // additional code
    var id = event.target.id;
    //alert(id);
    //alert($(this));
    _formurl = "home_stocktake_locations_list_group.php";
    _formdata = {
        'store_id': id
    };
    _formurl2 = "home_stocktake_list.php";
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: _formurl,
            data: _formdata,
            success: function(xhrResponse) {
                $('#current').html(xhrResponse);
                var rowCount = $('#locations').length;
                row_count = parseInt(rowCount);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#alert_msg').html(errorThrown);
                $('#alert_msg').fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: _formurl2,
            data: _formdata,
            success: function(xhrResponse) {
                $('#previous').html(xhrResponse);
                var rowCount = $('#dd_home_stocktake').length;
                row_count = parseInt(rowCount);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#alert_msg').html(errorThrown);
                $('#alert_msg').fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });

});
```

When I look at what happens in the console, only `home_stocktake_locations_list_group.php` file gets called, the second AJAX call is completely ignored. What is causing this?

In the console I can only see the following:

[image: request]

Comment: In my experience, 2 ajax requests dependent on each other are hard to maintain. I would say, by design ajax can chain .done() to verify that the first ajax is done. Completed/Succeeded are not the same with ajax so be careful!

Answer (score 1):

After the first `$.ajax` you have a `,` (comma), replace by a `;` (semicolon). Othen than that, it worked fine for me.

Also, if you are sending data on the request, consider using [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) instead of the lower level `$.ajax`. Also, you have the same error routine, so isolate it:

```
function handleError(xhr, status, error) {
  $('#alert_msg').html(error);
  $('#alert_msg').fadeIn('slow');
}

$.post(_formurl, _formdata)
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#current').html(data);
    var rowCount = $('#locations').length;          
    row_count = parseInt(rowCount);
  })
  .fail(handleError);

$.post(_formurl2, _formdata)
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#previous').html(data);
    var rowCount = $('#dd_home_stocktake').length;          
    row_count = parseInt(rowCount);
  })
  .fail(handleError);
```

Comment: Tried that and the console still only sees one request, please see my edited post with a screenshot

Comment: @artlemaks, I expanded my answer, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are done asynchronously, so you could start them one after the other directly (i.e. **no comma before you second $.ajax command**).

If your AJAX requests depend on each other and must be done in a specific ordre, start the second request in the "success" portion of the first request.

Comment: I have tried removing the comma before the second command. I tried it without a comma and with a semicolon (;) between the two requests, but still only the first one seems to be getting called. The requests are not depended on each other

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo has it right.  Lose the `,` after the first `$.ajax` and replace with a `;`

ie

```
}),
$.ajax({
```

becomes

```
});
$.ajax({
```

Comment: If the first answer was correct, what about your answer makes this particular one more useful?  It may benefit you to [edit] more clarity, and format with code blocks for the changes suggested, as well.

Answer (score 0):

make each request in separate promises and when all promises have been resolved on then function fire the event to change the DOM.