# running two ajax same time, one ajax call is using done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading stackoverlow and found that there many questions related to this tag, i want to run two piece of codes simultaneously

using the $when

my code looks like this, but not sure how can i rewrite it, please guide

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#Button',function (e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var isExcel = document.getElementById('Excel').checked ? 1 : 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: "page1",
            cache: false,
            data : $('#form').serialize(),
            method: "post",
            success: function(response){
                $('.mytable').show();
                $('.mytable').html(response);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            
            $("#datatables").DataTable({
                "bFilter": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "deferRender":true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : "/data.cfm",
                    "type" : 'post'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        
        if(isExcel) {
            $.ajax({ // 2nd call
                url: "/excel.cfm",
                cache: false,
                data : $('#form').serialize(),
                method: "post",
                success: function(response){
                    alert('done');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

please guide how can i make it work using when, because the ajax call with datatables will bring the results back, the excel might take a while

Comment: Have you tried merely taking out the line `if(isExcel) {` (and its corresponding closing `}`)? Because otherwise the two Ajax calls should be working simultaneously.

Comment: So you want to run both ajax requests at the same time, but only run the datatable update once both have finished?

Comment: `const requests = [$.ajax(...)];` then `if (isExcel) requests.push($.ajax(...));`. Now you can do `$.when(...requests).then(...);` (untested)

Comment: if you just need to run code simultaneously as you mentioned it in the description, please try to check out this post(https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730566/6901693)? Please let us know if you wish to have it a bit differently or you need a bit more information on this topic

Comment: i want that when i click the hit button, it goes to the ajax call first which brings the datatables and start showing it, if the excel checkbox is checked, it calls another jquery ajax which generates the file from a different code in excel, but but the datatables should be visible and in running state

Comment: What does your code do that's different from the above comment/description?   Start both requests, when datatables finished, update the table, when excel finished call `alert`?

Answer (score 1):

> I want that when i click the hit button, it goes to the ajax call first which brings the datatables and start showing it.
> If the excel checkbox is checked, it calls another jquery ajax which generates the file from a different code in excel, but the datatables should be visible and in running state.

If you want the Excel part to run *after* the datatables returns, you should add the Excel request in the done callback of the datables call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#Button',function (e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var isExcel = document.getElementById('Excel').checked ? 1 : 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: "page1",
            cache: false,
            data : $('#form').serialize(),
            method: "post",
            success: function(response){
                $('.mytable').show();
                $('.mytable').html(response);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            
            $("#datatables").DataTable({
                "bFilter": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "deferRender":true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : "/data.cfm",
                    "type" : 'post'
                    }
                }
            });

            if(isExcel) {                                 // moved here
                $.ajax({ // 2nd call
                    url: "/excel.cfm",
                    cache: false,
                    data : $('#form').serialize(),
                    method: "post",
                    success: function(response){
                        alert('done');
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        // removed excel request from here
    });
});
```